# Can the paste command correctly put two unicode files side by side without duplicating any unicode BOM?

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

This is the version of paste that I am using.

```
C:\cygwin\bin>.\paste.exe --version
paste (GNU coreutils) 8.26
Packaged by Cygwin (8.26-2)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.
This is free software: you are free to change and redis
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David M. Ihnat and David MacKenzie.

C:\cygwin\bin>
```

I am not sure if it's most up to date, as I don't see paste listed here, which is where I guess i'd look to update

[image]

But I have the paste command installed in cygwin.

But it's not working.. It is inserted extra characters

xxd -p  is a command that shows hex.

file1.txt and file2.txt are two UTF-8 files

> ```
> C:\cro\a>file file1.txt
> file1.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with no line terminators
>
> C:\cro\a>file file2.txt
> file2.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with no line terminators
> ```

file1.txt has the code for utf-8 bom, that's EFBBBF  followed by the hex for the letters 'aaa'.  file2  has the text bbb.

> ```
> C:\cro\a>xxd -p file1.txt
> efbbbf616161
>
> C:\cro\a>xxd -p file2.txt
> efbbbf626262
> ```

We see that here. Don't worry about the `´╗┐` that's just cmd trying to show UTF-8 BOM. That's not the issue I have.

> ```
> C:\cro\a>type file1.txt
> ´╗┐aaa
> C:\cro\a>
> C:\cro\a>type file2.txt
> ´╗┐bbb
> C:\cro\a>
> ```

The problem is that the paste command, when I use it to try to put file1 and file2 side by side, as you see looking at the hex, it has duplicated the unicode bom (efbbbf), and it shouldn't.

> ```
> C:\cro\a>paste file1 file2 >a.a
> paste: file1: No such file or directory
>
> C:\cro\a>paste file1.txt file2.txt >a.a
>
> C:\cro\a>type a.a
> ´╗┐aaa  ´╗┐bbb
>
> C:\cro\a>xxd -p a.a
> efbbbf61616109efbbbf6262620a
>
> C:\cro\a>
> ```

Is there a later version of paste for windows that doesn't do that?  Or does this problem exist even in the latest linux version of paste.. And is there a way around it?

It the meantime i'll encode utf-8 files without the BOM, before using paste.

Answer (score 0):

Past belongs to coreutils.

You can use the search on the website
https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fcoreutils%2Fcoreutils-8.26-2&grep=bin%2Fpaste

or `cygcheck -p bin/paste`

As of course it does not care of the encoding if you have two BOM
you will have a duplicate.